# Local Hook not working

Tags: winapi, hook, setwindowshookex, findwindow

I have an application and wish to monitor *MSWord* keypressing (LOCAL HOOK), but I cant figure out how to find the pid to be used! The bellow CODE WORKS GOOD with global hook (`pid` = `0`) and with (`pid` = `GetCurrentThreadId`). But doesn´t work with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`:

```
      HWND hWindow = FindWindowEx(NULL,NULL,String("Notepad").w_str(),NULL);
if (!hWindow) {
   ShowMessage("hWindow fail");
   return;
}

unsigned long pid;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow ,&pid);

//pid = GetCurrentThreadId();
if (!hWindow) {
   ShowMessage("pid fail");
   return;
}

String s = "HookDLL.dll";
DllHandle=LoadLibrary(s.w_str());
HOOKFCT_2 InstHook=reinterpret_cast<HOOKFCT_2> (GetProcAddress(DllHandle,"InstallHook"));

if(!InstHook(pid, (void *)(callIt) ))
{
    Label1->Caption="Unable to install mouse hook!";
}
else Label1->Caption="Mouse hook installed!";
```

I will be very, very gratefuLl for any light on the problem...

Notice:

1. I wish a hook to *MSWord* only.
2. The above code works, failling only when trying to hook on another application (i.e.: not using `pid`=`0` or `pid`=`GetCurrentThreadId`), resulting in = *"Unable to install mouse hook!"*.
3. I already try `FindWindow`, `FindWindowEx`, `GetForegroundWindow`, `GetActiveWindow`; since not of this works, I belive the problem is `GetWindowThreadProcessId`.

Comment: `GetCurrentThreadId` only returns a thread ID, not process ID. You should use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to retrieve the process ID that own the specified window. Note that the window must belong to the *MSWord* application. Also check for that hook DLL documentations for any limitations. Without details on what method that hook DLL uses, it's impossible to guess what might cause the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`SetWindowsHookEx` requires *thread ID*, not process ID. Pass thread ID instead:

```
DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow, 0);

if(!InstHook(threadID, (void *)(callIt) )) {...}
```

Comment: Ok, my error I'm thinking GetWindowThreadProcessId returns the threadId into second argument (passed by ref). THANKS